# Iteratively going through XML file, storing sets of values from different tags

Tags: python, xml

I am new to parsing XML into Python and I was looking for a bit of guidance of where to go next. For one thing I have been using Minidom and I have read that using Element Tree is far easier, but nonetheless I have been trying with Minidom anyway.

So I have a musicXML file and I am looking to parse the data within Python. I have made a list of all the tags which I require and placed them in their hierarchical order as shown below:

```
<Part id = "P1">  
    <measure id = "0">  
        <note>  
            <pitch>  
                <step> G <\step>  
                <octave> 4 <\octave>  
            </pitch>  
            <duration> 2 </duration>  
            <type> quarter </type>  
        </note>  
    </measure>  
    <measure id = "1">  
         ....  
    </measure>  
    ...  
</Part>`
```

---

Apologies for the lack of formatting, I wasn't sure how to indent it all properly, took longer than I will admit to work out how to take a new line. The tags step and octave are both on the same level contained within pitch, and duration and type are on the same level as pitch, contained within note.

Anyway back to what I want to do, that is just what one part looks like, there are more part ids but for the sakes of this question let us just assume there are two. Basically I want to be able to record the values of groups of each step and its octave, coupled with its duration and type and which measure it originated from, and of course the order which each of these groups comes in the measure.

So we could have within measure (G,4,2,quarter), (F,4,2,quarter), (C,4,2 quarter), (D,4,2, quarter). Would it be possible to store all these and access them again through an index? Keeping in mind that in this example there are 15 measures for each of the 4 parts, which means storing an index value for the individual values contained inside 60 separate measures.

I understand this a very heavy worded question and I hope someone can actually make sense of my ramblings, if I have been to vague about anything please do ask for more information. All of this data is going to be stored in a database, I just need the best way of actually taking the data out of the xml and formatting it to be stored, especially since the note values and the time values still have to be manipulated into numbers instead of musical terms once I have them all into Python. Thanks for any assistance it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Easy it is, maybe an example will convince you:

On Ubuntu OS:

sudo apt-get install python2.6-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev

pip install lxml

```
from lxml import objectify

root = objectify.fromstring(<your input string>)
print root.measure[1].attrib["id"]
```

for more details see http://lxml.de/objectify.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I tried it however and got a ton of errors 
  File "parser.pxi", line 650, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:75363)
  File "parser.pxi", line 590, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:74696)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1

those are just some of the errors

Comment: I guess your xml input is still invalid, I can see the slashes there to the wrong side in some tags, also make sure you take out the .... lines and the ' and the end of the string.... well, it needs a valid xml... try to read the errors carefully

Comment: Those were just my errors typing it in, I do have an actual valid xml file which I was able to read with Minidom, the ellipsis was just to show that there are many more measures inside the first part.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ and share your xml, lxml should be able to load any valid xml